# ActiveModel contact form sends email but message body does not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the contact form setup and I can receive the emails after the form is submitted. I can't seem to figure out how to include the form entries in the email.

For example the two fields the user must fill out is their email and the body of the message. When I receive the email I do not have none of that user filled information included in the email. The only information I am receiving is from the view that's inside /contact-mailer/new_contact.html.erb which is `Thank you for sending us a message!`

contact_mailer.rb:

```
  def new_contact(contact)
      @contact = contact
      mail(to: 'username@gmail.com', subject: 'Contact us Form')
    end
```

Contacts controller:

```
  def create
      @contact = Contact.new(params[:message])
      if @contact.valid?
        ContactMailer.new_contact(@contact).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
```

Contacts model:

```
  include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :email, :content

    validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

    def initialize(attributes={})
      attributes && attributes.each do |name, value|
        send("#{name}=", value) if respond_to? name.to_sym 
      end
    end

    def persisted?
      false
    end
```

/contacts/new.html.erb:

```
<% title "Contact Us" %>

<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content, "Message" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Send Message" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Logs:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-17 14:38:16 -0400
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WN19FGciesn2QUiaMtxv4Lwo48tRTkFBSud7OPGRTts=", "contact"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "content"=>"This should be included in the email."}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`auth_token` = 'Mqy5_1kyb4hAsrmB9Q0fug' LIMIT 1
  Rendered contact_mailer/new_contact.html.erb (0.4ms)

Sent mail to username@gmail.com (2687.6ms)
Date: Thu, 17 Apr 2014 14:38:16 -0400
From: no-reply@domain.com
To: username@gmail.com
Message-ID: <53501f989f98b_ed7833109c4539dc@Macintosh.local.mail>
Subject: Contact us Form
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<p>Thank you for sending us a message!</p>


Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2768ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the /contact-mailer/new_contact.html.erb to include your contents, 
please address [Action Mailer docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

For example:

```
<p> The following contact registered: </p>
<p> Email: <%= @contact.email %> </p>
<p> Content: <%= @contact.content %> </p>
```

Comment: I did that prior to posting here and it never posted the information as the email and content remained blank. I c&p yours to double check and the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I see! So the problem is that you don't have a :message attribute in params.

Comment: It should be @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact]) in the controller

Comment: ahh silly me forgot to change that over. Thanks for the noob point out